# Mean io cant install module meanio

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean-stack

I am trying to install mean io app and i get this error when its come to meanio module.

```
npm WARN locking Error: EACCES, open '/Users/netanelbasal/.npm/_locks/cookie-parser-a838fb939a0365d3.lock'
npm WARN locking  /Users/netanelbasal/.npm/_locks/cookie-parser-a838fb939a0365d3.lock failed { [Error: EACCES, open '/Users/netanelbasal/.npm/_locks/cookie-parser-a838fb939a0365d3.lock']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo chown -R $USER ~/.npm
```